# Command-line Equivalent to MacOSX stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" on Linux?

Tags: linux, osx, stat

I need to extract the timestamp of when a file has been <del>created</del> modified for the first time. The files are on a server and can be accessed from MacOSX via sshfs, as well as from a Ubuntu server. Under MacOSX bash I can extract the location and timestamps of a filetype using this command:

```
find . -iname '*.txt' -exec stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" "{}" > timestamps.csv \;
```

Is there any way to implement this under Linux bash?

Many thanks in advance,

Geo

Comment: your text says "created" but the commands show "modified", which is it?

Comment: The earliest modified date coincides closely with the creation date in my files which is why used this command (and forgot about the difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this close enough?

OSX:

```
$ stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N" *
1531851236  Jul 17 11:13:56 2018 bar
1531851236  Jul 17 11:13:56 2018 baz
1531851236  Jul 17 11:13:56 2018 foo
1531851236  Jul 17 11:13:56 2018 quux
```

Linux:

```
$ stat -c "%Y   %y %n" *
1531851190  2018-07-17 11:13:10.640328282 -0700 bar
1531851190  2018-07-17 11:13:10.640328282 -0700 baz
1531851190  2018-07-17 11:13:10.640328282 -0700 foo
1531851190  2018-07-17 11:13:10.640328282 -0700 quux
```

Bear in mind that some Linux filesystems do not by default track the *creation* time ("`Birth`" time) of a file:

```
$ stat foo
  File: foo
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd00h/64768d    Inode: 262180      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/   redacted)   Gid: ( 1000/   redacted)
Access: 2018-07-17 11:13:10.640328282 -0700
Modify: 2018-07-17 11:13:10.640328282 -0700
Change: 2018-07-17 11:13:10.640328282 -0700
 Birth: -
```

Comment: It's the birth time that I'm after. I saw some info regarding Linux kernel is not tracking creation time, but that was in 2014. Extracting birth time via OSX is useful but not sustainable for my project as it eventually should run under Linux.

Comment: In your sample command you wanted emulated, you are presenting "last modified time", which is what my Linux example also provides.  If the underlying filesystem does not track a datum, how would you propose to extract it exactly?

Comment: There is a difference in your timestamps though. Even worse, in my OSX/Linux comparison the difference is a whole week:  `stat -f "%m%t%Sm %N"` results in `1531161405 Jul  9 11:36:45 2018` on OSX, but `stat -c "%X   %x %n"` becomes `1531792913   2018-07-16 19:01:53.516613900`

Comment: `889192457 44470 -rwxrwxrwx 1 (1096826171 (1096811009 0 768040960 "Jul 16 19:01:53 2018" "Jul  9 11:36:45 2018" "Jul  9 11:36:45 2018" "Dec 31 16:00:00 1969" 65536 1500080 0` (OSX) - I guess I want the earliest modified date.

Comment: There is a difference in the timestamps because I logged into one system and `touch`ed the files; then logged into another system and `touch`ed another set of files.  The comparative point in my example was the output format, not the actual timestamp itself.

Comment: So, the answer would be `stat -c "%Y   %y %n"` ?

Comment: Just so.  Using `X` and `x` was erroneous on my part.